# Deploying React app with Vite in Heroku returns 404 status code

Tags: reactjs, heroku, http-status-code-404, vite

I'm having problems trying to access my website, it returns 404 status code.

I'm using React with Vite and Heroku.

**I'm using this buildpack as it says in Vite docs:**

*Vite Heroku Deploy Doc:* https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#heroku

*Heroku Buildpack for static file:* https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

**Website page:**

[image]

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**Static.json file:**

[image]

**Package.json file:**

[image]

**Vite.config.ts file**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are having deployment issues with ANY single page application, use the following buildpack and make sure you are specifying the root folder of your bundled application

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

Answer (score 0):

**This error can occur when:**

**1 -** You don't specify in *static.json* file the index route. To solve it, just add this few lines:

```
"routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
}
```

Now you are saying that all routes redirects to **index.html** file.

If, for some reason, you want to add more routes for different html files, just do this:

```
"routes": {
    "/": "index.html",
    "*": "404.html"
}
```

In above example, when request reaches "/" route, it redirects to **index.html**, but if request uses any different route, it redirects to **404.html** file.

**2 -** It also can happen when you don't have **heroku/nodejs** buildpack installed in your Heroku app.

If you are using Vite, you have to install both **heroku/nodejs** and **heroku/heroku-buildpack-static**

To install it you can access your **app** in heroku website, then go to **settings**, finally click on **add buildpack** button, place this url,save it and redeploy:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This didn't work for my heroku deployment. 
so i deployed to vercel and got the same problem
I know the question is for heroku but still if you are looking for vercel
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66686684/15721021) worked for me

Comment: This will solve the 404 error, however it led me to another error, a Heroku one. Logs from the command `heroku logs --tail` show `npm ERR! Missing script: "start"` which is weird because it was supposed to run the index.html in the dist folder.