# Routing with react-router-dom using react vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

> Blockquote

How do I route to the next page or another page using VITE?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, using `vite`, to redirect to another page we need to import the following lib:

```
import { navigate } from 'vite-plugin-ssr/client/router';
```

Don't need to create **const variables**, but have a caveat, this just work using `Client Routing`, on the other hand, you can use:

`window.location.href = YOUR ROUTE`

See the [documentation](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/navigate) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In Vercel this can be done by adding a rewrite to config file in the root of the project called

```
vercel.json
```

https://vercel.com/docs/configuration
Add rewrites for all routes to the file that point to '/' or '/index.html'

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

or

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

Refence: [Vite.js React Build Not Redirecting On Netlify And Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667636/vite-js-react-build-not-redirecting-on-netlify-and-vercel/66686684#66686684)

Answer (score -1):

All your routing can be done via react-router-dom

Use `Navigate`, `Redirect` or `useNavigate` provided by react-router-dom

Please go through the docs and try to implement before asking